# How to achieve UILabel line breaks only on a specific separator character?

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel

I have a string which has a separator character between words (Words with spaces) eg.

```
"Male • 89 • Senior Citizen • Side Lower Berth • Non Veg • Bedroll"
```

So "•" is separator here. Now while assigning it to a multiline label I want line breaks only on this separator. Eg. I don't want line breaks in between "Side Lower Berth" so that some part of it rendered in the first line and remaining one in next line. It should draw it next line only by making the decision based on the defined separator "•" here.

[image]

Comment: is your output should be "Male
 89 
 Senior Citizen 
 Side Lower Berth 
 Non Veg 
 Bedroll" ?

Comment: Nope. It's nothing to do with output. the question is related to the UILabel drawing and its line break.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all of your ordinary spaces with nonbreaking spaces, except in the places where you want to allow that break the line. (So leave an ordinary space after each bullet)

Comment: Non-breaking spaces mean?

Answer (score 1):

What if you jump lines when • appears? If you wanna try :

```
yourString.replacingOccurrences(of: "•", with: "\n")
```

I don't know if that's what you want, if not, sorry.